# Let me change the related site while starting the chat-room with a user

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

When I tried to start chat-room with a [user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/133951/swami-vishwananda),
[image: screen-shot]

I clicked on "start a new room with user" and chat-room [created](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29870/room-for-pandya-and-swami-vishwananda) under specific site : Unix & Linux. It may be because the parent site of [my profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/115725/pandya) is Unix & Linux.

So, **Why is there an option for specific site not provided?**, Unlike when starting a [new](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new) room?

> [image: screen-shot]

So, I am requesting a **feature for changing related site while starting room with a [user](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users)**. Now what can I do in oder to start room with user with another related site? (for instance, [Hinduism](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com))

- Do I have to change my parent site?!
- Or Is it possible to change the parent site for [current](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29870/room-for-pandya-and-swami-vishwananda) room? (For instance I want related site: [Hinduism](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=hinduism.stackexchange.com))

Comment: When you start a new room you become the room owner. That makes it logical to associate the room with the site linked to your parent user/site. As most chatrooms are not really on different domains (there only three chatservers, stackoverflow, meta and stackexchange) there isn't much need to get the link right. I didn't test but I assume your suggestion to first change your parent user before you create the room could associate the room to the site you choose (assuming if you an account there).

Comment: @rene ok. I've changed my parent site and it works (temporary solution). But I think it is better to provide a feature as explained in question (permanent solution)  . What do you think about feature-request to SE?

Comment: Well, this got 4 upvotes and no downvote so far so your FR is OK. And the team sees all bug and feature requests so when they see fit it might get implemented. Chat is not the highest priority so it might take a couple of [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) before this gets done.